# sequelize oneToMany create nested associations

Tags: sequelize.js

Is there a way to have sequelize create nested associations via a single create call?
For example if I have a model `Data` that `hasMany` of model `User`, and each user `hasMany` of model `Permission`. Is there a way to just call `Data.create` with a `Data` containing `User` and `Permission`, and sequelize will create the nested associations?

The only thing I've found on the sequelize docs is using `include` to pull in nested associations on a `find` call, or calling a setter after `Data.create`, e.g. `data.setUsers(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this can be done only if all the records are new. In your case that means having a new `Data` with new `User`s who also have new `Permission`s. Otherwise, you'll have to do it the "manual" way.

For more info, see the documentation here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#creating-with-associations